# regex of file name format

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to create a python regex of following string: 
 `ABC--2000-01-10X13-11-44.237Z--572b3b7681572b3b7681572b3b7681572b3b7681`
This is what I managed: 
 `^ABC\S\S[0-9A-T\S.]{24}\S\S[a-z0-9]{40}$`

The problem is python keeps complaining about anomalous backslashes missing or r prefix, I've tried both suggestions without luck. I manage to make it stop cry about backslashes by replacing `\S` with `-` so the regex looks like this instead:
`^ABC--[0-9A-T-.]{24}--[a-z0-9]{40}$` 
But now it doesn't match any longer and I think it's because of the punctuation `.`? I'm not sure and I hope someone is willing to help me fix this.

Comment: show us some of your input string that you want to match

Comment: @AlwaysSunny The string is the first bold declaration, and the regular expression is the second.

Comment: Do you know what `\S` matches? `[0-9A-T\S.]{24}` is strictly equivalent to `\S{24}`

Comment: @Toto of course it is supposed to march hyphen.

Comment: `\S` matches any character that is not a space, it is the opposite of `\s`, so `0-9`, `A-T` and `.` are included in `\S`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your **SECOND** regex, Actually it is not matching because you've used the character range like `[0-9A-T-.]{24}` but in your given input string you've a character called **X** so I think you need to modify your existing regex e.g `A-T` to `A-Z` then it will match your string perfectly.

```
^ABC--[0-9A-Z-.]{24}--[a-z0-9]{40}$
```

**REGEX** : https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/24

**Python Code:**

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^ABC--[0-9A-Z-.]{24}--[a-z0-9]{40}$"

test_str = "ABC--2000-01-10X13-11-44.237Z--572b3b7681572b3b7681572b3b7681572b3b7681"

matches = re.search(regex, test_str, re.IGNORECASE)

if matches:
    print ("Match was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(start = matches.start(), end = matches.end(), match = matches.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(matches.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = matches.start(groupNum), end = matches.end(groupNum), group = matches.group(groupNum)))
```

Comment: Escape the dash in character class or put it at the beginning or at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your regex as **raw** string (*r'...'*):

```
pat = re.compile(r'^ABC\S\S[0-9A-T\S.]{24}\S\S[a-z0-9]{40}$')
```

Otherwise (in a "normal" string) backslashes must be doubled.

Example (working) code:

```
import re

str = 'ABC--2000-01-10X13-11-44.237Z--572b3b7681572b3b7681572b3b7681572b3b7681'
pat = re.compile(r'^ABC\S\S[0-9A-T\S.]{24}\S\S[a-z0-9]{40}$')
print(pat.match(str).group())
```

Comment: I got result: `ABC--2000-01-10X13-11-44.237Z--572b3b7681572b3b7681572b3b7681572b3b7681`. Python 3.7 + Jupyter.